# Store dataset count as a variable in a report to use in other tables - SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

We have 2 queries on an SSRS report .

One query returns a single number that is a total record count.
The other query returns a single column that we'd like to divide by the total returned in the first query.

So

Query 1 DATASET (this will always return a single value)

```
TOTAL  
100
```

Query 2 DATASET (this will return a list of values we'd like to divide by q1 answer)

```
COL A
1
20
3
49
```

What we want to show on the report

```
RATIO (A/Total)
1/100
20/100
3/100
49/100
```

Not show how to marry these two datasets in a single ssrs tablix.  The 100 is not an aggregate of any value in the table from set 2, its a totally different number so I don't know of a way to write a query to bring out these values ins a single dataset.

Ideas?

thanks,.

MC

Comment: I am not sure if you can show data from two datasets into one data pane you will need to create one dataset and code your query in a way that it produces the required results. can you show your both queries ???

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to combine your datasets, you can do the following to achieve your end result.

For the dataset that returns a single value, you could create a report parameter (@MyParam) that is hidden and is populated by your dataset Query1. Your dataset for Query2 can remain as it was. Then you can use the following expression to populate a textbox in your report

```
=CString(Fields!ColA.value) &"/"& CString(Parameters!MyParam.value)
```

If that is put in a list or table, it will go through each value in ColA and produce your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do one data set?  Err...I assume you want to see 49/100 and not .49 with this answer

```
select q2.A + '/' + q1.value as 'output'
from query2 q2, query1 q1
```

It's a cross join and applies q1 values to all q2 (since q1 is just one value, this'll work)...query1 and query 2 can be replaced with whatever queries you want to have there...you'll need to provide the SQL for q1 and q2 if you want a more full answer